# How to set a Woocommerce sidebar change to dropdown menu in responsive mode?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, drop-down-menu, responsive

In WordPress shop page I have right **sidebar** [image: product category as a sidebar].

It has no problem when using a desktop.

But in responsive mode or mobile mode sidebar drops to the downside of the page. [image: responsive iPhone x]

as you can see sidebar is under the products `container`

I would like to encapsulate like the main menu on the right side of the page when it appears on mobile or in responsive mode.

Comment: I had same problem but I let it go.

Comment: any solutions yet?

Comment: @KaranSethi I solved it by changing to question but indeed still it is.